# Invertir una cadena de caracteres en SL

Tags: array, pseudocódigo, sl

Tengo el siguiente pseudocódigo en lenguaje Sl. EL programa pretende invertir una cadena de caracteres, imprimiendo la cadena pero de derecha a izquierda.
El programa compila pero se tranca al momento de terminar de introducir la frase, y no se por qué.

```
variables
  i,j : numerico
  largo : numerico
  cad : cadena
  auxiliar : cadena
  
inicio
  cls()
  auxiliar = ""
  imprimir("Introduzca una cadena de como máximo 20 caracteres: ")
  leer (cad)
  
  largo = strlen(cad)
  
  i = largo
  
  desde j=1 hasta largo {  
    auxiliar[j]=cad[i]
    i=i-1
  }
  imprimir(auxiliar)
  
fin
```

Sl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
variables
  i : numerico
  largo : numerico
  cad : cadena
  auxiliar : cadena

inicio
  cls()
  imprimir("Introduzca una cadena: ")
  leer (cad)

  largo = strlen(cad)
  auxiliar = strdup(" ", largo) //strdup es repetir

  desde i=1 hasta largo {
    auxiliar[largo - i + 1] = cad[i]
  }
  imprimir(auxiliar)

fin
```